# How can I use Socket.IO with promises?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, promise

As a part of an ongoing effort, I'm changing my current callbacks technique to promises using `blue-bird` promise library.

I would like to implement this technique with Socket.IO as well.

- How can I use Socket.IO with promises instead of callbacks?
- Is there any standard way of doing it with Socket.IO? any official solution?

Comment: If you are not strongly stuck to Socket.IO, you may consider plain websockets wrapped into promises. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304996/javascript-using-promises-on-websocket

Answer (score 3):

You might look into [Q-Connection](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-connection), which facilitates RPC using promises as proxies for remote objects and can use Socket.IO as a message transport.

Answer (score 1):

Bluebird (and many [other](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) [promise](https://github.com/then/promise#promisenodeifyfn) libraries) provide helper methods to wrap your node style functions to return a promise.

```
var readFile = Promise.promisify(require("fs").readFile);

readFile("myfile.js", "utf8").then(function(contents){ ... });
```

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification

> Returns a function that will wrap the given nodeFunction. Instead of
>   taking a callback, the returned function will return a promise whose
>   fate is decided by the callback behavior of the given node function.
>   The node function should conform to node.js convention of accepting a
>   callback as last argument and calling that callback with error as the
>   first argument and success value on the second argument.

Comment: Sure, I know that, but I'm looking for an official support for socket.io/promises like mongoose's `exec()` which returns `Promise` object.

Comment: Gotcha.  Most websocket modules use evented api's. It is easy to convert a callback based api to promises, less so with something that uses eventemitter.

Answer (score 1):

have a look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-rpc

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var rpc = require('socket.io-rpc');

var rpcMaster = rpc(io, {channelTemplates: true, expressApp: app})
        //channelTemplates true is default, though you can change it, I would recommend leaving it to true,
        //                   false is good only when your channels are dynamic so there is no point in caching
    .expose('myChannel', {
    //plain JS function
    getTime: function () {
        console.log('Client ID is: ' + this.id);
        return new Date();
    },
    //returns a promise, which when resolved will resolve promise on client-side with the result(with the middle step in JSON over socket.io)
    myAsyncTest: function (param) {
        var deffered = Promise.defer();
        setTimeout(function(){
            deffered.resolve("String generated asynchronously serverside with " + param);
        },1000);
        return deffered.promise;
    }
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    rpcMaster.loadClientChannel(socket,'clientChannel').then(function (fns) {
        fns.fnOnClient("calling client ").then(function (ret) {
            console.log("client returned: " + ret);
        });
    });

});
```